# Google Chromecast In-Manifest Subtitles

Tags: ios, google-cast

**Chromecast VOD casting with subtitles.**

We are trying to get our project to display subtitles when casting VOD in our project.

The problem is that **we are not using external URL's for our subtitles** since our subtitles are ***embedded*** into our VOD, but based on the Google Cast documentation, still, we have to create our own MediaTrack that contains the link to our external `.vtt` in order to work, which by providing a dummy link to an external `.vtt`, it worked, but we want somehow access the in-manifest subtitles without providing the external link to a .vtt

My question, is there support on the Google Cast SDK that can handle in-manifest subtitles, can we send `remoteMediaClient?.setActiveTrackIDs[someID]` to our receiver in order to display the in-manifest subtitle **without** creating the `MediaTrack` with the external `.vtt` link?

For a reference, Android version on the same project, successfully showed subtitles simply by switching and calling the `setActiveTrackIDs` without even creating the `MediaTracks`, because the receiver already contained the `MediaInfo` with the `MediaTracks` inside. Is this possible with the iOS SDK as well?

**Every help is appreciated.**

```
func closedCaptionPressed(sender: UIButton) {
castContext.sessionManager.currentSession?.remoteMediaClient?.setActiveTrackIDs([index])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the media is fully loaded the in-manifest subtitles are available through the [MediaInformation mediaTracks](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_information.html#a751ed326ca3868e0d22114935588db9b). The CAF receiver identifies the in-manifest subtitles by default so you shouldnt need to create extra media tracks.